# GCC 4.8.1 + Binutils 2.23.52 on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ubuntu, ld, opensuse, binutils

How comes that on ubuntu 13.10 with gcc-4.8.1 required version of binutils 2.23.52, but on OpenSUSE 13.1 with gcc-4.8.1 required version of binutils is 2.23.2?

On ubuntu 13.10+ I always get ld errors when tryin to build application (with binutils 2.23.52 or 2.24 on ubuntu 14.04), but everything is ok in OpenSUSE 13.1 or Ubuntu 13.04 with binutils version 2.23.2. GCC version is the same - 4.8.1.

I can manually downgrade binutils on ubuntu 13.10+ to 2.23.2 and get correctly built application. Is there any disadvantages of this method (downgrading binutils) if I really need older version of this package.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You wiil lose binutils-gold that inserted in binutils-2.23.52 and got some troble with compilation for arm64.
you can find more informationn in changelog http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/b/binutils/binutils_2.23.52.20130913-0ubuntu1/changelog.
I think you need not downgrade. You can fix trouble on 2.23.52 by adding LDFLAGS="-lm"

Answer (score 1):

When using -O2, -O3 optimization with GCC 4.8+, binutils < 2.23.52 fails assembly on some infrastructures with "expecting string instruction after `rep'".

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57017#c7

Comment: I encountered this issue in RHEL